# How do I import pywin32 on blender?

Tags: python, api, blender

I just approached blender and after studying python for a good week I decided to also use blender. I have seen some tutorials, created a plan and a "ball" with a camera inside that moves, to manage the movement on two axes I have not used python which for the rotation is necessary.
However, I had thought of using ctypes to calculate the size of the window and pywin32 to center the mouse on the screen ( depending on the size that was calculated using ctypes ) and then receive input from blender to move the mouse. the script works fine in debug python but blender tells me that it can not load libraries. Searching on google I found that it depends on the version of Python installed and the version of the library.
can you help me to find these libraries, or if it is not possible can you tell me an alternative method to do so?
PS: If needed I can post the draft of the script but still lacks the management part of the camera just because I was going to write while working with blender .

Python 3.4.0
Blender 2.7.0

Answer (score 0):

I installed blender there:

```
C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender
```

So I looked for a folder named `site-packages`. There it is:

```
C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.68\python\lib\site-packages
```

All additional *Python* modules, packages must be copied/installed into the `site-packages` folder. Blender modules will be put somewhere else, I guess.

I suggest

1. you search for 'blender install packages pypi'
2. you just install a package (e.g. pywin32) for an installed python and copy it from the Python site-packges to the Blender site-packages.

After you installed and or copied it to there you can import it.